# \fbox command destroys margin

Tags: spacing, margins, boxes, framed

I included a graphic the following way:

```
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{questionnaire1.png}
```

Then I changed it so that a frame is drawn around the graphic:

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{questionnaire1.png}}
```

But now, the whole graphic with the border is move 1-2 cm to the right side of the page so that is not in line with the other content. How can I change this?

Comment: How do you use this exactly? Does it start a new paragraph, i.e. is there a empty line before it?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer The picture has exactly the size of a whole page. So there is no paragraph.

Comment: The size doesn't matter. There might be a paragraph nonetheless.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer Yes that's true, I tried \centering for each graphic and this would work, but I think the better solution would be the code in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Probably related question [spacing - Non-invasive replacement for \fbox? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43904/non-invasive-replacement-for-fbox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add `\noindent` to avoid paragraph indention, which might be the case here. Also the `\fbox` adds some space around its content, i.e. `\fboxsep` on each side. I would subtract this amount from the image width to have the image including the frame exactly `\textwidth` wide. You could also subtract the line width of the frame as well.

```
\noindent\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax]{questionnaire1.png}}
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but unfortunately I get an exception ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   *
l.136 ...p-2*\fboxrule\relax]{questionnaire1.png}}
                                                  
? ´

Comment: @Roflcoptr: I fixed it. The `*` caused the troubles. They are not required anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on why it is moving. Probably you forgot `\fboxsep`, `\fboxrule` and/or `\parindent`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\fbox{%
 \color{red}\rule{\textwidth}{1cm}}

\noindent\fbox{%
 \color{red}\rule{\textwidth}{1cm}}

\noindent\fbox{%
 \color{red}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}{1cm}}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
 \fbox{%
  \color{red}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth}{1cm}}}

\noindent
 \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt
 \fbox{%
  \color{red}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule}{1cm}}
 \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, `\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]` is probably the best thing to do. With `[c]` as second optional argument you can center the image even when it is wider than `\textwidth` when the frame is added.