# Non-invasive replacement for \fbox?

Tags: spacing, boxes

I am trying to create a macro that improves on `\fbox` by working correctly in all cases and by being minimally invasive with respect to padding. What I've got so far works fairly well, but I'm having trouble measuring text width, height, and depth in certain cases. My question is *How do I calculate these correctly?*

**Why I don't like \fbox:**

1. Notice below how `\fbox` gets the bounding boxes correct on the ‘,’ and the ‘l’, but completely messes up the fraction size when invoked as `$\frac{\fbox{1}}{\fbox{2}}$` and the superscript size when invoked as `$x^{\fbox{2}}$`.
2. `\fbox` draws a rule *around* the bounding box rather than inside it. Thus, no matter how thin the rule, it still alters the dimensions of the text being boxed. In other words, `\fbox` is not minimally invasive. Below, the padding and line thickness are set with `\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}` and `\setlength\fboxrule{0.001pt}`. Setting `\fboxrule` to `0pt` causes the rule to disappear altogether.

[image: \fbox hello world]

**First attempt at a non-invasive box (using \vrule):**

My first attempt used a `\vrule`. This was good, but it obscured text when the bounding box overlapped another character, for example the ‘r’ below. Worse yet, I didn't see how I could draw a dark rule around the box. So I threw out that idea.

[image: \vrule hello world]

**Second attempt (using TikZ):**

Next I used TikZ to draw a translucent filled box. The edge is not a stroked path around the box but rather is four very thin filled rectangles *inside* the bounding box.

[image: \fillbox hello world]

Now this is getting somewhere. The problem, however, is in how I’m measuring the width, height, and depth of the bounding box. I'm using `\settowidth`, `\settoheight`, and `\settodepth` and giving these the value `#1` passed to the macro. This approach works great for regular text, but once something is in a superscript, subscript, a fraction, or a stacked relation—or in any other font or size for any reason—it breaks down.

**Problems:**

As you can see, the widths, heights, and depths of certain elements below have been calculated incorrectly.  The most egregious of is the `\cdot`, whose bounding box appears to its left because my macro doesn't know that it is a binary relational operator needing extra space. I'm not sure if that is fixable, but is there at least some way to fix the superscripts and subscripts? Because although `$v_{\fillbox{x}}$` comes out with undisturbed spacing, it's measuring the size of `x`’s bounding box based on `#1` being `x` (normal size and style) and not `_x` (subscripted math size and style).

[image: \fillbox code]

Finally, why does the stacked relation disturb the horizontal spacing?

**Minimal working example:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newlength\fillbox@height%
\newlength\fillbox@depth%
\newlength\fillbox@width%
\newcommand{\fillbox}[1]{%
  \ifmmode%
    \settoheight{\fillbox@height}{$#1$}%
    \settodepth{\fillbox@depth}{$#1$}%
    \settowidth{\fillbox@width}{$#1$}%
  \else%
    \settoheight{\fillbox@height}{#1}%
    \settodepth{\fillbox@depth}{#1}%
    \settowidth{\fillbox@width}{#1}%
  \fi%
  \raisebox{-\fillbox@depth}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \pgfsetfillcolor{yellow!90!red}
    \pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}
    \pgfsetrectcap
    \fill (0,-\fillbox@depth) rectangle (\fillbox@width,\fillbox@height);
    \pgfsetfillcolor{yellow!50!black}
    \pgfsetfillopacity{1}
    \fill (0,-\fillbox@depth)
          rectangle (\fillbox@width,-\fillbox@depth+.1pt);
    \fill (0,\fillbox@height)
          rectangle (\fillbox@width,\fillbox@height-.1pt);
    \fill (0,-\fillbox@depth)
          rectangle (.1pt,\fillbox@height);
    \fill (\fillbox@width,-\fillbox@depth)
          rectangle (\fillbox@width-.1pt,\fillbox@height);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \kern-\fillbox@width%
  }%
  #1%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vskip1em
$\fillbox{p}_{\fillbox{x}}
  \mathrel{\stackrel{\fillbox{_{~+}}}{\fillbox{\leftarrow}}}
  \fillbox{(}\fillbox{\frac{\fillbox{1}}{\fillbox{2}}}\fillbox{\cdot}
  \fillbox{a}_{\fillbox{x}}\fillbox{\cdot}%
  \fillbox{\Delta}\fillbox{t}^{\fillbox{2}}\fillbox{)} \fillbox{+}
  \fillbox{(}\fillbox{v}_{\fillbox{x}}\fillbox{\cdot}%
  \fillbox{\Delta}\fillbox{t}\fillbox{)}$\fillbox{;}\par
$\fillbox{v}_{\fillbox{x}}
  \mathrel{\stackrel{\fillbox{_{~+}}}{\fillbox{\leftarrow}}}
  \fillbox{a}_{\fillbox{x}}\fillbox{\cdot}%
  \fillbox{\Delta}\fillbox{t}$\fillbox{;}\par

\vskip1em
$p_x \mathrel{\stackrel{_{~+}}{\leftarrow}}
  (\frac{1}{2}\cdot a_x\cdot\Delta t^2) + (v_x\cdot\Delta t)$;\par
$v_x \mathrel{\stackrel{_{~+}}{\leftarrow}} a_x\cdot\Delta t$;\par

\end{document}
```

*(Note: I didn't tag this question with `tikz` because even though it uses TikZ, the question is really about spacing and boxing; TikZ just happens to be used.)*

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-best-debug-latex may be relevant.

Answer (score 16):

Any box commands in math mode need to be set in all styles so TeX can pick the right one later; the `\mathchoice` command is what you need here. See my [rant against `\over`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42855/whats-behind-over) on this site the other day:-) If you just use `\hbox{$...$}` you are starting a fresh math list at text size even in subscript position.

You can re-assert the correct spacing around your construct using `\mathbin` `\mathop` and friends, This could be done automatically by looking up the`\mathcode` of the character you are boxing. Inspecting `bm.sty` might be helpful, which does this to re-assert the correct math class after making things bold, but the issues are similar.

It's a bit late to re-create `bm` interrogation of `\mathcode` so this just looks at special cases `\cdot` and `+` but otherwise does something plausible I suspect

**UPDATE** At the end I place a version that does automatically pick up the math class from character tokens, things like `\cdot` defined by `\mathchar` and things like `\log` with explicit `\mathop`. I will leave the original version in place as the math class detection probably obscures the logic of the measuring which was perhaps the main part of the question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,color}

\makeatletter

\def\fb@cdot{\cdot}
\def\fb@p{+}
\def\@mfbox#1{%
\def\fb@{#1}%
\ifx\fb@\fb@cdot\mathbin\fi
\ifx\fb@\fb@p\mathbin\fi
{\text{\fboxsep\z@\colorbox{yellow}{$\m@th#1$}}}}
\def\@tfbox#1{{\fboxsep\z@\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}}
\def\fillbox#1{\ifmmode\expandafter\@mfbox\else\expandafter\@tfbox\fi{#1}}


\begin{document}

\vskip1em
$\fillbox{p}_{\fillbox{x}}
  \mathrel{\stackrel{\fillbox{_{~+}}}{\fillbox{\leftarrow}}}
  \fillbox{(}\fillbox{\frac{\fillbox{1}}{\fillbox{2}}}\fillbox{\cdot}
  \fillbox{a}_{\fillbox{x}}\fillbox{\cdot}%
  \fillbox{\Delta}\fillbox{t}^{\fillbox{2}}\fillbox{)} \fillbox{+}
  \fillbox{(}\fillbox{v}_{\fillbox{x}}\fillbox{\cdot}%
  \fillbox{\Delta}\fillbox{t}\fillbox{)}$\fillbox{;}\par
$\fillbox{v}_{\fillbox{x}}
  \mathrel{\stackrel{\fillbox{_{~+}}}{\fillbox{\leftarrow}}}
  \fillbox{a}_{\fillbox{x}}\fillbox{\cdot}%
  \fillbox{\Delta}\fillbox{t}$\fillbox{;}\par

\vskip1em
$p_x \mathrel{\stackrel{_{~+}}{\leftarrow}}
  (\frac{1}{2}\cdot a_x\cdot\Delta t^2) + (v_x\cdot\Delta t)$;\par
$v_x \mathrel{\stackrel{_{~+}}{\leftarrow}} a_x\cdot\Delta t$;\par

\end{document}
```

Version using `bm`-style math class detection.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,color}

\makeatletter

\def\fb@eat#1#2#3#4#5{\futurelet\fb@let@token\fb@eat@}
\def\fb@eat@#1\fb@eat{%
\ifx\fb@let@token\bgroup
\else\ifx\fb@let@token\mathop
  \mathop
\else\ifx\fb@let@token\mathbin
  \mathbin
\else\ifx\fb@let@token\mathrel
  \mathrel
\else\ifx\fb@let@token\mathopen
  \mathopen
\else\ifx\fb@let@token\mathop
  \mathop
\else\ifx\fb@let@token\mathpunct
  \mathpunct
\else\ifcat.\ifcat a\noexpand\fb@let@token.\else\noexpand\fb@let@token\fi
  \afterassignment\fb@mathchar\count@\mathcode`#1\relax\fb@eat
\else\ifx\fb@let@token\mathchar
  \afterassignment\fb@mathchar\expandafter\count@\@gobble#1\relax\fb@eat
\else
    \xdef\meaning@{\meaning\fb@let@token}%
    \expandafter\fb@mchar@test\meaning@""\@nil
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}


\def\@mfbox#1{%
\begingroup
\let\protect\empty
\expandafter\fb@eat\romannumeral`\Q#1\relax\fb@eat
  \ifcase\count@
    \or
    \mathop\or
    \mathbin\or
    \mathrel\or
    \mathopen\or
    \mathclose\or
    \mathpunct\or
  \fi
{\text{\fboxsep\z@\colorbox{yellow}{$\m@th#1$}}}%
\endgroup}

\edef\fb@mchar@{\meaning\mathchar}

\def\fb@mchar@test#1"#2"#3\@nil{%
  \xdef\meaning@{#1}%
  \ifx\meaning@\fb@mchar@
    \count@"#2\relax
    \fb@mathchar\fb@eat
   \fi
}

\def\fb@mathchar#1\fb@eat{%
 \divide\count@"1000 }

\def\@tfbox#1{{\fboxsep\z@\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}}
\def\fillbox#1{\ifmmode\expandafter\@mfbox\else\expandafter\@tfbox\fi{#1}}


\begin{document}


$a-b$

$a{-}b$

$a\fillbox{-}b$

$\log x + \mathrm{log}x$


$\fillbox{\log} \fillbox{x} \fillbox{+} \fillbox{\mathrm{log}}\fillbox{x}$


$\fillbox{0}$

$ a \cdot b {\cdot} c$

$ a \fillbox{\cdot} b \fillbox{{\cdot}}c $


$a \fillbox{\mathchar"2201} b  \fillbox{{\mathchar"2201}} c $


$ a - b < \alpha $

$\fillbox{a} \fillbox{-} \fillbox{b} \fillbox{<} \fillbox{\alpha}$

$\fillbox{a+b}$

$a = \sqrt{h}$

$a = \fillbox{\sqrt{h}}$


\vskip1em
$\fillbox{p}_{\fillbox{x}}
  \mathrel{\stackrel{\fillbox{_{~+}}}{\fillbox{\leftarrow}}}
  \fillbox{(}\fillbox{\frac{\fillbox{1}}{\fillbox{2}}}\fillbox{\cdot}
  \fillbox{a}_{\fillbox{x}}\fillbox{\cdot}%
  \fillbox{\Delta}\fillbox{t}^{\fillbox{2}}\fillbox{)} \fillbox{+}
  \fillbox{(}\fillbox{v}_{\fillbox{x}}\fillbox{\cdot}%
  \fillbox{\Delta}\fillbox{t}\fillbox{)}$\fillbox{;}\par
$\fillbox{v}_{\fillbox{x}}
  \mathrel{\stackrel{\fillbox{_{~+}}}{\fillbox{\leftarrow}}}
  \fillbox{a}_{\fillbox{x}}\fillbox{\cdot}%
  \fillbox{\Delta}\fillbox{t}$\fillbox{;}\par

\vskip1em
$p_x \mathrel{\stackrel{_{~+}}{\leftarrow}}
  (\frac{1}{2}\cdot a_x\cdot\Delta t^2) + (v_x\cdot\Delta t)$;\par
$v_x \mathrel{\stackrel{_{~+}}{\leftarrow}} a_x\cdot\Delta t$;\par

\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

Comment: This is starting to look really good! Is it possible to make the box color translucent so that nesting is visible? And with a thin border on the interior of the box?

Comment: I imagine that xcolor or one of the newer packages can do translucent color, If you know the syntax feel free to edit the answer instead of the simple "yellow" . I've not actually written any TeX for a decade so I'm sticking to what I know this week, hence just original color package syntax.   Inner border of the box is doable but a bit of a pain as I don't think `\fcolorbox` works with negative `fboxsep` (as it's basically `\fbox`) so I'd have to implement the rules from scratch, but probably the definition of `\fcolorbox` can be copied more or less..

Answer (score 2):

In response to the questioner's desire to fix the box issue for sub and superscripts, the `scalerel` package has the means to carry the current math style into places where it would otherwise be lost.  The syntax is `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` which will import the math style in force at location `\ThisStyle` to the spot where `\SavedStyle` is invoked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\fboxsep=0pt
\newcommand\boxit[1]{\ThisStyle{\fbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}}}
\begin{document}
\[
y = x^{\boxit{2}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]