# Create rotated prime symbol

Tags: symbols, rotating

I would prefer to work with a prime symbol that is less rotated. I tried the following

```
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\newcommand*{\p}{\turnbox{12}{$\,'$}\;}
```

which is visually what I desire. If I now write something like

```
$a+b\p$
```

things work fine, but when I use `\p` in subscript contexts

```
$a_{c\p,d}+b\p$
```

the symbol is not scaled and not placed right. Of course one can always work with hacks such as

```
$a_c\turnbox{12}{${}_{'}$}_{,d}+b\p$
```

but perhaps anyone knows of a simple solution?

Comment: If you want a *completely vertical* prime, the `textcomp` package provides `\text{\textquotesingle}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\mathchoice` to adjust the size depending on the math context as follows:

[image]

### References:

- For more details on `\mathchoice` see [Is there a test for the different styles inside maths mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/is-there-a-test-for-the-different-styles-inside-maths-mode), and [Proper use of \mathchoice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43978/proper-use-of-mathchoice).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\newcommand*{\p}{%
    \mathchoice%
        {\turnbox{12}{$\displaystyle\,'$}\;}%
        {\turnbox{12}{$\textstyle\,'$}\;}%
        {\turnbox{12}{$\scriptstyle\,'$}\;}%
        {\turnbox{12}{$\scriptscriptstyle\,'$}\;}%
}%

\begin{document}
$a+b\p$

$a_{c\p,d}+b\p$
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, after a subscripted variable, I use this as `\!\p`, not just `\p`. (Compare `\(s_1\p\)` with `\(s_2\!\p\)`.)