# Is it possible to rotate a prime when you have a subscript too?

Tags: rotating, subscripts, superscripts

So I want an apostrophe to denote the complement, but the ^\prime symbol looks a bit too angled.

I found somewhat of a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47791/create-rotated-prime-symbol).

But I can't get it to work with subscripts, `A_0^\prime` yields:

[image]

But I want the prime sign rotated 12 degrees to the left. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

With a slightly modified definition from [the answer to "Create rotated prime symbol"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47791/create-rotated-prime-symbol) (removing the trailing `\;`) it works.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\newcommand*{\p}{%
    {\mathchoice%
        {\turnbox{12}{$\displaystyle\,'$}}%
        {\turnbox{12}{$\textstyle\,'$}}%
        {\turnbox{12}{$\scriptstyle\,'$}}%
        {\turnbox{12}{$\scriptscriptstyle\,'$}}}%
}%

\begin{document}
$A\p_0$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to move the prime symbol a bit closer to the center of the zero?

Comment: In the definition of `\p`, replace `\,` by `\:`.

Comment: Thanks, solved all my problems.

Comment: @John Just wait a bit, there is always another problem around the corner. (Optimistic quote of the day)

Comment: You were right, is there another way to adjust the displacement of the prime other than \, or \: , like can you specify the amount of pixels or inches you want to move it?

Comment: Nevermind, found out you could do it with \hspace{}

Comment: @John `\kern` comes to mind ...

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
              A_{0}^{\prime}
    \end{align} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}


\newcommand{\pp}{\rotatebox{20}{\prime}}

\begin{document}
    $A^{\pp}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems the OP aims at a prime symbol that is rotated to the left. `$A'$` is basically the same as `$A^\prime`$