# (Nonfatal but Symptomatic) Conflict of amsmath and mathstyle Packages

Tags: math-mode, packages, amsmath, incompatibility, subscripts

This was brought to my attention by our colleague, Lover of Structure, but since it affects my *scalerel* package (which began using the *mathstyle* package to detect the current math style, as of version 1.4) it is now my problem too.

I even think I know why it happens, and I have a workaround, but I was hoping for a more satisfying solution.  Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathstyle}
\newcommand*{\testcmd}{\(M_{\texttt{k}}\)}
\begin{document}
\(M_{\texttt{k}}\)  \par
\testcmd
\end{document}
```

and here is the result.

[image]

In it you see two different sized subscripts (call them small and large, respectively), which would not seem obvious from code.  Investigating, I found that:

1) with neither package loaded, both subscripts are large

2) with only amsmath loaded, both subscripts are small

3) with only mathstyle loaded, both subscripts are large

4) with both packages loaded (as in my MWE), the first is small, the second is large

5) with both packages loaded, if the definition of `\testcmd` is moved after `\begin{document}`, both subscripts are small (this is what I call the WORKAROUND).

6) If I load *mathstyle* before *amsmath*, the code breaks, saying `\dfrac` is already defined.

"Aha," I say to myself.  It would appear that one of these packages is using a "feature" I've seen mentioned wherein certain commands are loaded just prior to `\begin{document}`.  But this would seem to put a significant constraint on users of these two packages (or users of *amsmath* and *scalerel*); namely, one would be forbidden from defining math command shortcuts in their document preamble.

So, my questions are these:  am I understanding the nature of the problem properly?  Is there a fix that would still allow users to define math shortcuts in their preamble, while using the package combination?

Comment: early in the user's guide for `mathstyle` (`texdoc mathstyle`) it says "If you want to use this package with `amsmath`, it is important `mathstyle` is loaded
after `amsmath`."  some reasons for this are given later in the documentation.  (the author of `mathstyle` isn't currently active with latex as far as i know.)

Comment: `\usepackage{mathtools}` loads the full mh bundle and amsmath after which example looks fine for me.

Comment: @texenthusiast Actually, replacing the `amsmath` with `mathtools` in my MWE left the behavior unchanged.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes i don't know much, but see [workaround and myouput](http://i.imgur.com/SUVQJLy.png)

Comment: Why not use `\mathchoice` in your package rather than use mathstyle. TeX would have been better without mathchoice but it is what it is but redefining _every_ command that makes a sub or superscript or fraction just to save yourself three boxing operations is a high price to pay and will make your package incompatible with other things and have weird load order constraints.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, I need to learn about `\mathchoice`.  I had only learned of mathstyle recently out of need at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78872/how-to-capture-the-current-math-style.  Obviously, I need to rethink.

Comment: Note to readers: `scalerel` package has been updted (V1.5) to eliminate the use of the the `mathstyle` package, which brought on the problems noted in this question.  It now uses `\mathchoice` and the incompatibilites have been eliminated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mathstyle does

```
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\^=12\relax \catcode`\_=12\relax}%
```

If you need definitions in the preamble you could just execute that earlier.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathstyle}
\catcode`\^=12\relax \catcode`\_=12\relax
\newcommand*{\testcmd}{\(M_{\texttt{k}}\)}
\begin{document}
\(M_{\texttt{k}}\)  \par
\testcmd
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much (to you and the removed but like-minded comment of Herr Vogt)!  In addition, the `scalerel` manual compiles with this option set, appearing not to break anything. Are there any drawbacks/restrictions when employing this option?  Let me attempt to see if this resolves Lover of Structure's larger problem before accepting the answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes see my comment on your question. Stuff will break.

Comment: Note to self: executing that `\catcode` command in package xyz means that package xyz needs to be loaded after `\usepackage{verbatim}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That will be the first of a _long_ list of incompatibilities and ordering issues make sure you have a big piece of paper for your notes:-)