# Globally defined macro changes numerical value

Tags: macros

In experimenting with `\ThisStyle`, I have come across the following very weird behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\foo{%
    \ThisStyle{%
        \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle o$}%
        \global\edef\myheight{\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}%
        \textrm{Written \string\myheight\space as \meaning\myheight;~}%
    }%
    \textrm{reading \string\myheight\space as \meaning\myheight}%
}
\begin{document}
    $\foo$
\end{document}
```

The results is this:

```
Written \myheight as macro:->4.30554pt; reading \myheight as macro:->2.15277pt
```

Effectively, the globally `\edef`ed macro (set only a single time) changes its value between setting and accessing, and the numerical value corresponds to exactly half the desired value. Why is that?

Comment: It’s because `\ThisStyle` invokes `\mathchoice`, which executes the code for *all* the four possible styles, in the order  `\displaystyle`/`\textstyle`/`\scriptstyle`/`\scriptscriptstyle`; so, `\box0` is set equal to the four variants in turn, and only the last assignment remains in effect.  Maybe I’ll find the time, later on, to write a complete answer, if nobody has done it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As long as you recall it within the scope of the current** `\ThisStyle`, it will remember the height (but will lose valid memory of it upon exit from `\ThisStyle`).  Here, I moved the closing brace of the `\ThisStyle` *after* the `\textrm` invocation.

As Gustavo commented, `\ThisStyle` invokes the standard LaTeX `\mathchoice`, which builds 4 styles of boxes and figures out which one to set at the last moment.  This means that the last box built will be the `\scriptscriptstyle` box, and residual measurements and global definitions from the `\mathchoice` will be associated with that one only, once the `\ThisStyle` scope has been exited.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\foo{%
    \ThisStyle{%
        \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle o$}%
        \global\edef\myheight{\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}%
        \textrm{Written \string\myheight\space as \meaning\myheight;~}%
    %
    \textrm{reading \string\myheight\space as \meaning\myheight}}%
}
\begin{document}
    $\foo$
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, here is the best that a `\mathchoice` approach can do...it can save all 4 heights globally in different macros, but it will not remember the particular style that applied at the time, inside the `\mathchoice`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\makeatletter
\def\foo{%
 \ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle o$}%
   \expandafter\xdef\csname myheight\m@switch\endcsname{\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}%
   \textrm{Written \string\myheight\space as %
     \expandafter\meaning\csname myheight\m@switch\endcsname;~}%
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\foo $

$\scriptstyle\foo$

But here are the 4 sizes globally saved:\\
Display style: \myheightD\\
Text style: \myheightT\\
Script style: \myheightS\\
Script-Script style: \myheights
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not solve the problem, because after that `\myheight` will expand to `2.15277pt` nonetheless. The OP's aim is to have it defined to the height plus depth of the actually typeset material and that's the reason for having the second `\textrm` outside of `\ThisStyle`.

Comment: @egreg It will not solve a global definition issue, nor did I say it would.  I only indicated that one could reliably employ the value only within the scope of the `\ThisStyle`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `mathstyle` instead of `scalerel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathstyle}

\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \sbox0{$\currentmathstyle o$}%
  \xdef#1{\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}%
  \texttt{\footnotesize\meaning#1}%
}

\begin{document}

$\foo\myheightT$ has value \myheightT

$_{\foo\myheightS}$ has value \myheightS

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, the `mathstyle` package has its own set of problems...https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114467/nonfatal-but-symptomatic-conflict-of-amsmath-and-mathstyle-packages

Answer (score 3):

`\ThisStyle` is implemented through `\mathchoice`; in practice, this means that its argument is processed four times, one for each of the four possible math styles, and the resulting four math lists are stored away and used later, during the process of converting a math list into its horizontal equivalent, when the actual math style to use becomes known.  This entails that each assignment contained in the argument is executed four times too, so that, if it is a global assignment, only the effects of the last one will survive.  And since the order of execution is `\displaystyle` -> `\textstyle` -> `\scriptstyle` -> `\scriptscriptstyle`…