# Stop custom counter from incrementing twice in align* environment

Tags: xetex, amsmath, mathtools

This took me hours to track down, partially because I am fairly new to TeX. I want to understand why the custom counter `eqpart`  in the following code fails to increment properly when using `mathclap`. The counter jumps from a to d. The first equation only has the right counter because it is not wrapped in `mathclap`. Removing `mathclap` from `ubrace` gives the correct count which is b.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{eqpart}[section]
\setcounter{eqpart}{0}
\renewcommand{\theeqpart}{\alph{eqpart}}

\newcommand*{\ubrace}[3][black]{
\colorlet{current}{.}
\color{#1}
\underbrace{#2}_{ \mathclap{ #3 } }
\color{current}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tageqpart}[1]{%
\ifmeasuring@\else
\refstepcounter{eqpart}
\displaystyle(\theeqpart)
\fi
\@bsphack
\protected@write\@auxout{}
{\string\newlabel{#1}{{(\theeqpart)}{\thepage}}}
\@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \underbrace{x + y}_{ \tageqpart{test1} } = 0
  \end{align*}
  \begin{align*}
    \ubrace{x + z}{\tageqpart{test2}} = 0
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
Heeding the advice of David Carlisle I have refined the `\ubrace` command as:

```
\newcommand*{\ubrace}[3][black]{
  \begingroup
    \color{#1}
    \overbrace{#2}^{#3}
  \endgroup
}
```

Comment: `\mathclap` like any command using `\mathchoice` typesets its arguments 4 times display,text,script and scriptscript with the final version only being chosen later when the math list is finished. In classic TeX you can not detect this. Also why do you use `\colorlet` and explicitly save/restore the colour rather than simply using a group?

Comment: To learn about `\mathchoice` and its implications, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43978/proper-use-of-mathchoice

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the explanation of  `\mathcoice`. To answer your question I am not familiar with TeX. After learning more about a group I can see why it is a better choice. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work using `\mathclap`?

Comment: possibly you can set a global flag to avoid incrementing the counter (you'd need to \write in all cases though as only one will be used) I may look later

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you

- replace `\mathclap{#3}` with `\makebox[0pt]{$#3$}` -- the latter method doesn't mess with the counter `eqpart`; (Aside: Any "advantage" the `\mathclap` method may have, in terms of auto-sizing the result via `\mathchoice`, is illusory since `#3` is set in `\displaystyle` anyway, according to a subsequent part of your code.)
- add parentheses to the definition of `\theeqpart`, and simplify some of the subsequent code that involves `\theeqpart`;
- apply David Carlisle's suggestion and surround the substantive instructions of the `\ubrace` macro with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` -- letting you get rid of the `\colorlet{current}{.}` and `\color{current}` instructions.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{eqpart}[section]
\setcounter{eqpart}{0}
\renewcommand{\theeqpart}{(\alph{eqpart})}

\newcommand*{\ubrace}[3][black]{%
   \begingroup
   \color{#1}
   \underbrace{#2}_{ \makebox[0pt]{$#3$} }
   \endgroup
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tageqpart}[1]{%
  \ifmeasuring@\else
     \refstepcounter{eqpart}
     \displaystyle\theeqpart
  \fi
  \@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}
    {\string\newlabel{#1}{\theeqpart\thepage}}
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \underbrace{x + y}_{ \tageqpart{test1} } &= 0\\
    \ubrace{x + z}{ \tageqpart{test2} }      &= 0
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```