# How can I know if I am inside an equation environment if it's nested with others?

Tags: macros, environments, conditionals

I wanted to define some partial derivative commands that would be `\partial y/\partial x` if it was inside an inline equation and would use `\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}` if inside an equation environment. I searched around and came up with (honestly, probably from TeX.SE but I don't remember which question/answer it was):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pd}[2]{%
\def\@tempa{document}
\ifx\@tempa\@currenvir \partial {#1}/\partial{#2} \else
\def\@tempa{equation}
\ifx\@tempa\@currenvir \frac{\partial {#1}}{\partial {#2}}\else
\fi\fi
}
```

which was awesome! But then I tried using it inside:

```
\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
      f &= \pd{y}{x} \\
      g &= \pd{y}{z}
   \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
```

and it didn't render correctly because the current environment was `aligned` and not `equation`. I could add `aligned` to my if statement but then I'll need to add branches for all the varieties of `*matrix` and who knows what else. I could add a default so that if it's not in `document` it always renders with the `\frac{}{}` form.

But all of that just doesn't seem like the right way to go. Is there a way to see if the command is issued somewhere inside of an `equation` environment, even if it is somewhere up the environment tree?

Comment: related: [Is there a test for the different styles inside maths mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1223/579)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of `\mathchoice{displaystyle}{textstyle}{scriptstyle}{scriptscriptstyle}` is the canonical way of providing different math answers as a function of the current math style (regardless of what environment name is invoking the math).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\pd[2]{\mathchoice%
  {\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}%
  {\partial #1/\partial #2}%
  {\partial #1/\partial #2}%
  {\partial #1/\partial #2}%
}
\begin{document}
Inline it looks like $f =\pd{y}{x} $
\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
      f &= \pd{y}{x} \\
      g &= \pd{y}{z}
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I **knew** I wasn't doing it in a good way and yet hours of searching never turned this approach up. One day, maybe I'll finally figure out what magic words to use to find answers to LaTeX questions :/

Comment: @tpg2114 The basic vocabulary of magic words are 300 TeX primitives. The TeX primitive `\matchoice` was used here. If you know this vocabulary then you know the answer to potentially all problems and as a bonus: you don't need to use LaTeX, TeX is more simple.

Comment: Why `\makeatletter`?

Comment: @summer It was vestigial from a prior edit/copy/paste.  It has been removed.  Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @tpg2114  I recall when `\mathchoice` was a revelation to me, as well.  David's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43978/proper-use-of-mathchoice is excellent reading.  My answer at that same question is also further developed at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78872/how-to-capture-the-current-math-style