# How to create special math macros which preserve the current style?

Tags: amsmath

The mathtools package provides a number of commands like `\mathmbox` which preserve the current math style.  The process seems to involve a lot of `\expandafter`s, `\mathpalette` and `\m@th`.  The following MWE compiles, but the superscript should not be visible and is.  Also, how would I create a two argument macro (like `\savebox`) where only the second argument is in math mode?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathsbox}{\expandafter\mathpalette\expandafter\math@sbox}
\newcommand{\math@sbox}[1]{\sbox0{$\m@th #1$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  x^{\mathsbox{2}} = a
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am confident the `\ThisStyle` macro of the `scalerel` pacakge can help you, but I don't understand your quesiton fully.  What is `\mathsbox` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: With the modified code you get the exponent in scriptscript style, not in script style. Try adding `{}^2` after `a^{\usebox{\mybox}}` to see it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Exactly.

Comment: Isn't it what I say in my answer?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Actually, I'm not really trying to accomplish anything except master the process.

Comment: If you wish to learn more of the `\ThisStyle{}` "process", here are some relevant answers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78872/how-to-capture-the-current-math-style/114658#114658 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43978/proper-use-of-mathchoice/114594#114594

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\mathpalette` needs two arguments, the first of which should be a *two argument* macro. With your code, the call

```
\mathsbox{2}
```

expands to

```
\expandafter\mathpalette\expandafter\math@sbox{2}
```

and `\expandafter` does nothing at all, so you get

```
\mathpalette\math@sbox{2}
```

Now, `\math@sbox` is defined with a single argument, which is bad. According to the definition of `\mathpalette`

```
% latex.ltx, line 4289:
\def\mathpalette#1#2{%
  \mathchoice
    {#1\displaystyle{#2}}%
    {#1\textstyle{#2}}%
    {#1\scriptstyle{#2}}%
    {#1\scriptscriptstyle{#2}}}
```

you now get

```
  \mathchoice
    {\math@sbox\displaystyle{2}}%
    {\math@sbox\textstyle{2}}%
    {\math@sbox\scriptstyle{2}}%
    {\math@sbox\scriptscriptstyle{2}}}
```

This typesets four math subformulas expanding each argument; the first becomes

```
\sbox0{$\m@th\displaystyle$}{2}
```

and similarly for the other three. So `\box0` is set to a box containing an empty formula.

Even if you define `\math@sbox` with two arguments, you get nothing really useful, because `\box0` will turn out to be void.

If you want to properly save the box in the style current at the time of the definition, you can use the `mathstyle` package (but it has some quirks, beware).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathstyle}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathsavebox}[2]{%
  \global\setbox#1=\hbox{$\m@th\currentmathstyle#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  x^{\mathsavebox{\mybox}{2}} = a^{\usebox{\mybox}}{}^2
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The `{}^2` is meant to show that the exponent is in the correct style (with your code it isn't).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass *two* arguments to `\math@sbox`, the first will be the math style to be used.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathsbox}{\expandafter\mathpalette\expandafter\math@sbox}
\newcommand{\math@sbox}[2]{\sbox0{$\m@th #1#2$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  x^{\mathsbox{2}} = a
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Adding `\tracingmacros=1` will show you in the log file what arguments are being passed to each macro.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/15925 for a good description of the working of `\mathpalette`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Indeed - you didn't say what you wanted to use it for though.  Box 0 is mostly for local use.

Answer (score 3):

The `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` feature of the `scalerel` package can extend the current math style into places where it is normally lost, such as boxes.  However, to transport that saved data outside of the `\ThisStyle` group, an `\xdef` must be employed.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{scalerel,amsmath}
\newcommand{\mathsbox}[1]{\ThisStyle{\xdef\xyz{\fbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  x^{\mathsbox{2}} = a \quad\text{What was saved and boxed earlier?} \xyz
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save something in the current mathstyle in a box, you have to use LuaTeX.  It offers the `\mathstyle` primitive which can be used to query the current math style.

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\getmathstyle[1]{%
  \ifcase \mathstyle
    \let#1=\displaystyle
  \or
    \let#1=\crampeddisplaystyle
  \or
    \let#1=\textstyle
  \or
    \let#1=\crampedtextstyle
  \or
    \let#1=\scriptstyle
  \or
    \let#1=\crampedscriptstyle
  \or
    \let#1=\scriptscriptstyle
  \or
    \let#1=\crampedscriptscriptstyle
  \fi
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\mathsbox[1]{%
  \getmathstyle\currentmathstyle
  \global\setbox0=\hbox{$\m@th\currentmathstyle#1$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\mathsbox{\int}$ \box0

\[\mathsbox{\int}\] \box0

\end{document}
```

[image]