# Does \reflectbox or \rotatebox affect text size?

Tags: math-mode, rotating, size, reflection

I needed a quantifier that looks like an upside-down N so I defined

```
\newcommand{\namesym}{\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\mathsf{N}$}}}
```

In most places, this has about the same size as existing quantifiers like `\exists` and `\forall`. But when I use it in a subscript (in equation environment), `\namesym` looks way bigger than `\exists` and `\forall` (although smaller then when used outside subscript).

Why is this the case and what can I do about it?

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem, but wouldn't a `\reflectbox` without rotating be sufficient for an N?

Comment: you would see same with `\mbox` use `\text{\reflectbox{....` (from `amsmath`)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes I guess I copied this from another letter I must have turned around in the past.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, inserting `\text` in the command fixed the issue!

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348566/how-to-create-special-math-macros-which-preserve-the-current-style