# How to scale down the operation +,-?

Tags: symbols

The plus sign `+` or minus sign `-` in LaTeX is too big for me. I want to scale down these binary operation symbol at once, so that whenever I type `+`, it corresponds to a more little `+` symbol. How can I do this? And what method to scale  down the symbol is better?
(By the way, I'm using `mtpro2` now.)

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes Bold}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo,zswash,mtphrb]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{bm}
\setCJKmainfont{cwTeX Q Ming} %just a Chinese font
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
results:\\
$a+b$\\
$\bm{\mathrm{a}}+\bm{\mathrm{b}}$\\
$\mbf {a+b}$ %MathTimePro2 original command
\end{document}
```

Result of test code:
[image]

Comment: How much smaller should the symbol be?

Comment: I'm not sure should I better specified by percentage or an absolute size? In fact, I have no idea now. I need to trial-and-error and see the display. Maybe 80%. I guess.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using? If I do `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`, with `$(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})$`, I get a [decidedly smaller plus sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r5kg.png)

Comment: @egreg Wow! I haven't thought of that! I'm going to add my code.

Comment: @egreg Now I've edited.

Comment: @Eric As Boris says, somebody put their time into making a consistent math font (`mtpro2`, in this case). It wouldn't be too difficult to use the plus sign from `newtxmath`, but I'm not sure it's the right thing to do. Anyway, remove `\everymath{\displaystyle}`: it's one of the worst TeX hints around. And using a boldface font as main font is another very bad choice for your readers.

Comment: What is the flaw of `\everymath{\displaystyle}`? I used it simply because I personally like the fraction in inline mode not too short as default.

Comment: If you want somebody to see your query, you need to tell them they have mail like this: @egreg. You should not use `\\ ` to break lines outside special contexts (e.g. `tabular`, `array`).

Comment: @Eric So you like to spoil the typesetting, by adding large white stripes to your page. Well, the document is yours.

Answer (score 6):

1. Please do not do this.  A good font was carefully designed by a font designer, who supposedly spent years in training and then designed fonts, carefully balancing readability, harmony and tradition.  Making changes like this is like adding a moustache to a portrait in a gallery.
2. Instead, choose a font that corresponds to your tastes.  Here is a catalog of free mathematical fonts:  http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html.  Linux libertine, http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/linuxlibertine/, has smallish plus sign.

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend this approach of making `+` active in order to redefine it, because it will break things that are being added with `\dimexpr` and `\numexpr`.  However, to that end, I have also provided `\newplus` to redefine the `+` and `\oldplus` to turn it off, restoring the original use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\let\svplus+
\catcode`+=\active % Make + an active character
\def+{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{$\SavedStyle\scaleto{\svplus}{5\LMpt}$}}}}}% 
\catcode`+=12 %
\def\newplus{\catcode`+=\active }
\def\oldplus{\catcode`+=12 }
\begin{document}
New: \newplus

$A + B \svplus C$

$\scriptstyle A + B \svplus C$

$\scriptscriptstyle A + B \svplus C$

Old: \oldplus

$A + B \svplus C$

$\scriptstyle A + B \svplus C$

$\scriptscriptstyle A + B \svplus C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for using the `scalerel` package. :-)

Comment: @Mico Thanks.  The `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` approach to condensing `\mathchoice` options is so *revolutionary* `;^)` that even TeXperts can't believe it.  See comment following http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43978/proper-use-of-mathchoice/114594#114594