# Centralize an `\includegraphics` within a `\def`

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

This question is prompted by an answer I was giving [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223489/fbox-without-additional-v-space), in which I used `\includegraphics{...}` within a `\def` definition, in order to include graphics in an in-line context.

**Question:** How do I go about centralising the included graphic, when using in-line, without resorting to manual ways like `\hspace{}`? I tried with `\centering`, but that has no effect. I've added `fbox` in the example below to make it more apparent.

[image: in line graphic with(out) centering?]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,keystroke,scalerel}
\renewcommand{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\def\abcd{%
    {\centering \fbox{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}{X}}}
}

\begin{document}
    This is an in-line graphic \fbox{\keystroke{\abcd}}.

    This is an in-line graphic \fbox{\abcd} with some space on either side.
\end{document}
```

ps. I was using it in `\keystroke{...}` from the `keystroke` package, but the problem is more general, and can be described *without* the `keystroke` package. However, please do address this in your answer if it is any different from the case without using `keystroke`, as I would like to improve on my answer there.

Comment: You are adding an extra space to the right; use % after }.

Comment: Oh darn, I gotta be more careful with this in the future. you can leave an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: `\centering` is doing nothing in your example, but it isn't clear what you want it to do, `\fbox` fits closely around its content so there is nothing to centre?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, I was intending for the `\centering` to somehow apply to the `\keystroke`, not so much centering it in the `fbox` itself.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by others, there are several problems.  Stray spaces were creeping in, because lines inside a macro definition were not ended in a `%`.  Also, `\centering` has no relevance outside of TeX's paragraph setting mechanism, which does not apply inside an `\fbox`.  Finally, `\fboxsep` is a length, not a definition, and so should be set as such.  In TeX, that would be `\fboxsep=0pt\relax`, while in LaTeX, one can preferably use `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,keystroke,scalerel}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\newcommand\abcd{\fbox{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}{X}}}
\begin{document}
    This is an in-line graphic \fbox{\keystroke{\abcd}}.

    This is an in-line graphic \fbox{\abcd} with some space on either side.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, also fix `\renewcommand{\fboxsep}{0pt}`, which should be `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`.

Comment: @egreg Ack!! I didn't see that!

Comment: Simpler than loading `scalerel`: ``\includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`X]{example-image-a}``.

Comment: @egreg Geez...if I could downvote my answer, I would!