# How to see the box to debug or learn LaTeX?

Tags: align, boxes

For example, I want to see the boxes implicitly generated by `alignedat`. I want to see how `\lineskiplimit` and `\lineskip` work and also the particular spacing between the current row and the previous one. How to see the box? Or is there another useful technique to debug?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43904/non-invasive-replacement-for-fbox

Comment: See also lua-visual-debug (there's a quesiton on this site about it)